# Wildfly variable properties

Tags: properties, wildfly

standalone.bat

```
set "DBO_PATH=D:\test"
```

standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
    <bindings>
        <simple name="java:propertiesFileName" value="${DBO_PATH}/test.properties"/>
    </bindings>
    <remote-naming/>
</subsystem>
```

How to set the properties to Wildfly picks them up ??

How to use a relative path in the value standalone.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. In order to achieve the goal, you need to do following:

1. Set environment variable like `set "FOO=bar"`
2. Then change your standalone.xml to contain reference to ${env.FOO}: `<simple name="java:/Foo" value="${env.FOO}/test.properties"/>`.
3. You can check if the solution is working by running following Java EE 6+ code

   ```
   @Singleton
   @Startup
   public class StartupBean {

       @Resource(lookup="java:/Foo")
       String foo;

       @PostConstruct
       public void start() {
           System.out.println("java:/Foo = " + foo);
       }
   }
   ```

Please refer to http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-configuration/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-standalone-xml-or-host-xml for another possible solution.

Comment: Thank you, but why it don't work - <system-properties> 
  <property name="-Dlog4j.configuration" value="${env.DBO_PATH}/log4j.xml" /> 
  </system-properties>

Comment: I would try property name without '-D'